# Ruby on rails: perform SQL DATE_ADD() function and IF conditional

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I need this SQL query Rails-friendly:

```
SELECT *,
IF (store.availability_offset IS NULL, DATE_ADD(product.release_date, INTERVAL 0 DAY), DATE_ADD(product.release_date, INTERVAL store.availability_offset DAY))
FROM products JOIN stores ON product.store_id = stores.id
WHERE (DATE_ADD(products.release_date, INTERVAL stores.availability_offset DAY) BETWEEN '2013-06-12' AND '2014-07-12' OR DATE_ADD(products.release_date, INTERVAL 0 DAY) BETWEEN '2013-06-12' AND '2014-07-12');
```

This is my Rails query up to now:

```
@products = Product.joins(:store).where("products.release_date >= :start_date AND products.publishing_date <= :end_date)", :start_date => params[:search][:start_date], :end_date => params[:search][:end_date]")
```

What I want to do:

- implement the `IF` conditional in order to manage the stores `availability_offset` in case its value is NULL.
- implement the `DATE_ADD()` function to be able to add the `availability_offset` value to the date `release date`.

How can I do that without using SQL sintax, just ActiveRecord? Thank you!

Comment: What is your Database engine name ?

Comment: Hi, I work with MySQL.

Comment: I also need a DATE_ADD in Ruby (not Rails though) - bounty added

Comment: Can you post your migrations?

Comment: Have you considered storing 0 instead of NULL in 'store.availability_offset' ?

Answer (score 1):

You just copy your select of SQL into Rails ActiveRecord select. Try to do this:

```
@products = Product.select('products.*, IF(store.availability_offset IS NULL, DATE_ADD(products.release_date, INTERVAL 0 DAY), DATE_ADD(products.release_date, INTERVAL stores.availability_offset DAY)) AS store_availability_offset')
    .joins(:store).where("products.release_date >= :start_date AND products.publishing_date <= :end_date)", :start_date => params[:search][:start_date], :end_date => params[:search][:end_date]")
```

For your `if` statement in select, I use alias column into `store_availability_offset`. I hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

I would place the `if` conditional and the `date_add()` in the Product class, override the `release_date` attribute and keep the ActiveRecord query as you wrote it:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  def release_date
    read_attribue(:release_date) + (availability_offset ||0)
  end

end
```